# how to store some values into mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

how to store hours and minutes to mysql database ?

like that : 12.05 only

i have putted it to duable type but i have start_time and end_time

and i should comapre these two fields .

like that :

```
select * from time where 12.05 between start_time and end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) data type.

Use this format for your time `HH:mm:ss`:
Example: `12:05:00` or `12:05`

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6535e/1)

Comment: how to set it on 12 hours only pm and am

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is the [Time mysql type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html)

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because
>   the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which
>   must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval
>   between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even
>   negative).

Your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM time WHERE start_time <= "12:05" AND end_time >= "12:05"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `TIME` type in MySQL and assign it to your fields `start_time` and `end_time`.

Your query will become (example)

```
select * from time where start_time < "12:05" and end_time > "12:05"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

Answer (score 0):

Time DataType will work for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
This code may be helpful for proper understanding for you.
<?php 
  $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
  $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
  $roll_no=$_POST['roll_no'];
  $branch=$_POST['branch'];
  $semester=$_POST['semester'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $Day=$_POST['Day'];//name of the day
  $Month=$_POST['Month'];//name of the month
  $Year=$_POST['Year'];//name of the year
  $gender=$_POST['gender'];
  $password=md5($_POST['password']);

      //used to hold day month and year together
  $dob=date("$Year-$Month-$Day"); 


  $query = "INSERT INTO user_registration (first_name,last_name,user_name,roll_no,branch,semester,email,dob,gender,password) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$user_name','$roll_no','$branch','$semester','$email','$dob','$gender','$password')";

  $result = mysql_query($query);

   if($result) {
        echo "register successful!";
   }








?>
```